# Compare Two Datatables and common values updated in second datatable?

Tags: c#

I have two `DataTable`'s and I want to select the rows from the first one which are present in second data table

For example:

**Table 1**:

```
 ColA1   ColA2
 1      sampletext1
 2      sampletext2
 4      sampletext4
```

**Table 2**:

```
ColA1   ColA2
 1      
 2  
 2
```

I want output like this:

**Table 2**:

```
ColA1   ColA2
 1      sampletext1
 2      sampletext2
 2      sampletext2
```

i try below code but it doesn't work

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtprofit.Rows)    
{  
    DataRow[] Selected = dtAccount.Select("AccDesc= '" + dr["Account"] + "' ");
    if(Selected.Length>0)
    {
        dr["Type"] = Selected[0]["AccType"];    
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: foreach (DataRow dr in dtprofit.Rows)

{

    DataRow[] Selected = dtAccount.Select("AccDesc= '" + dr["Account"] + "' ");
if(Selected.Length>0)
{
    dr["Type"] = Selected[0]["AccType"];

}
}

Comment: Edit your question with your attempt

Comment: @RAMARAJ.M Can this be done in LINQ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this LINQ-query which joins both tables:

```
var commonRows = from row1 in Table1.AsEnumerable()
                 join row2 in Table2.AsEnumerable()
                 on row1.Field<int>("ColA1") equals row2.Field<int>("ColA1")
                 select new { row2, newValue = row1.Field<string>("ColA2") };
foreach (var commonRowInfo in commonRows)
{
    commonRowInfo.row2.SetField("ColA2", commonRowInfo.newValue);
}
```

Result:

```
1   sampletext1
2   sampletext2
2   sampletext2
```

Here's another (possibly less efficient) approach:

```
var t1Rows = Table1.AsEnumerable();
foreach (DataRow row in Table2.Rows)
{
    DataRow row1 = t1Rows.FirstOrDefault(r => 
        row.Field<int>("ColA1") == r.Field<int>("ColA1"));
    if (row1 != null)
        row.SetField("ColA2", row1.Field<string>("ColA2"));
}
```

Last but not least, here's an approach without LINQ that works even in .NET 1.1:

```
foreach (DataRow row in Table2.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] rows = Table1.Select("ColA1=" + row["ColA1"]);
    if (rows.Length >= 1)
        row["ColA2"] = rows[0]["ColA2"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var table1Dic = table1.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(dr => dr.Field<int>("ColA1"), dr => dr.Field<string>("ColA2"));
foreach (var row in table2.AsEnumerable()) {
    var key = (int)row["ColA1"];
    if (table1Dic.ContainsKey(key))
        row.SetField<string>("ColA2", table1Dic[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing First,Get all the records that are common in both Data Tables(No need of same structure of both datatable).
To select common rows use this code.

```
   var sameRecords = from table1 in dtFirst.AsEnumerable() join table2 in  secondDt.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<string>("abc") equals table2.Field<string>("def") where table1.Field<string>("abc") == table2.Field<string>("def") select table1;
        if (sameRecords .Count() > 0)
        {
           //Copy selected recors to the Data Table object

            DataTable dt =sameRecords .CopyToDataTable();
        }
```

Now You have all the Records which have common in both Data Tables according to the set criteria.
for updating Records in resultant DT object iterate on the Rows and manipulate whatever you want like this

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 //Place your code
}
```

Cheers...........Happy Coding